# Deploy cloud endpoints on custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm testing with Google Cloud Endpoints on App Engine and I've mapped my app to a custom domain. It appears that this is not possible. I've tried accessing the endpoint url, changing the host but this gives me a 404.
I've also tried to change the root url and backend url for the service, but then I get this error after deployment:

`Endpoints: https://test.neenbedankt.com/_ah/api/myapi@v1 Error: API root https://test.neenbedankt.com/_ah/api not allowed on host version.myappid.appspot.com`

Can somebody confirm this is a limitation? For my current project this would be a showstopper.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correct, you can not map to a custom domain at current.

Comment: Too bad, especially if you want to publish an API I think this would be a common case.

Comment: It's a non-trivial networking problem and something we certainly plan on supporting in the future. Keep in mind, Cloud Endpoints is a **combination** or App Engine **and** Google's API Infrastructure.

Comment: I totally understand and I'm glad it's on your radar, I'll just have to wait :)

Answer (score 3):

edit: Google CloudEndpoints 2.0 will support this, which is now BETA. As explained by Google in the link below.

Google has now announced this "will be supported" but has not given an ETA.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384#c44