# Deploy Google Endpoint in a custom Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there any problems using Google Cloud Endpoints with custom domain?

I was using it for some weeks then, after a deploy it stopped to work. I look here and I found  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122217/deploy-cloud-endpoints-on-custom-domain) that says it is not allowed yet.

But it was working for me on http://www.customdomain.com/_ah/api/app-id/v1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using App Engine's built-in support for custom domains as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain), it's not expected to work. You can follow [this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384) to keep up-to-date on the feature's progress.

Comment: after checking the the feature request page, it seems like this feature is yet to be added. Is it possible to provide some info on when this feature maybe released?

Answer (score 0):

Now,Google CloudEndpoints 2.0 support it

Migrating to version 2.0:

- Update your dependency to use the new artifact. In Maven, this looks
  something like below:

  com.google.endpoints endpoints-framework 2.0.0-beta.8
- Remove the legacy dependency, which is the appengine-endpoints artifact.
- Update the API entry point in your project web.xml file:

  - Rename all occurrences of SystemServiceServlet to EndpointsServlet.
  - Replace all occurences of the path /_ah/spi/* to the new required path  /_ah/api/*

See:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384