# Calling Google Endpoint api from a custom Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible to call, my endpoint api (https://myapi.appspot.com/_ah/api/) from my web app hosted in another domain (i.e. www.mydomain.com)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't with cloud endpoint version 1, as stated in the doc. It comes out of the box with version 2 (beta as of March 2017)

> Note: version 1 of the Google Cloud Endpoints Frameworks did not support custom domains but version 2 does.

Same question on stackoverflow:

- [App engine endpoints API - 404 with custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612705/app-engine-endpoints-api-404-with-custom-domain?rq=1)
- [Deploy Google Endpoint in a custom Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607664/deploy-google-endpoint-in-a-custom-domain?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course.

You can call your endpoints wherever you are.

[image: Endpoints basic architecture]

You can develop an App engine backend based on Enpoints and call them from Android, IOS or another web app.

It's like Google APIs. The same way to consume them.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/