# App engine endpoints API - 404 with custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to use custom domain with app engine. Everything works fine with localhost and [appspot url](https://conference-center-1177.appspot.com). But with [custom domain](https://cc.mdsarowar.me/) endpoints api doesn't work; the API discovery request (https://cc.mdsarowar.me/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/conference/v1/rest) returns `Not Found` with error code `404`.

Here is my app.yaml ([full code](http://pastebin.com/QTugNVts)):

```
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: conference.api
  secure: optional
```

And endpoints api ([full code](http://pastebin.com/RNusmh84)):

```
@endpoints.api( name='conference',
            version='v1',
            allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID, API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
            scopes=[EMAIL_SCOPE], hostname = 'cc.mdsarowar.me')
class ConferenceApi(remote.Service):
"""Conference API v0.1"""
........
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/):

> **Note**: Google Cloud Endpoints does not support custom domains.

**Edit**

There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384) for this so you may want to star it.